# Call difference function with difference input while pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery

html

```
text1:<input type="text" id="text1"/>
<br>
<br>
text2:<input type="text" id="text2"/>
<br>
<br>
text3:<input type="number" id="text3"/>
```

js

```
window.onkeydown = onKeyDownHandler;

function onKeyDownHandler(e)
{
    switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 13:
            if(text1){
            alert("text1 function");
            }else if(text2){
            alert("text2 function");
            }else if(text3){
            alert("text3 function");
            }
          return;
    }
}
```

I have 3 input fields which I want to do difference function while pressing enter. How do I get or detect which input field I am on? Is there some way I can check the id name when I click on the input field (focus), then somehow match the id name with in onKeyDownHanlder function case?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/61skufox/1/)

Something like this

```
if(focusidname = text1){
alert("text1 function");
}
```

Comment: Bind each input differently, or compare `e.target`

Answer (score 0):

use `document.activeElement.id` to get id of currently focused element.

```
if(document.activeElement.id == 'text1'){
alert("text1 function");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.target.id`:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event){
  alert(event.target.id);
};
```

However it seems that your approach to attaching events will cause troubles as more elements are added to page. I suggest you take a different approach:

Create a function that will detect enter key:

```
var whenEnterCall = function (callback){
  return function(event){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      callback(event);    
    }
  }
};
```

Attach it to a specific input

```
input.addEventListener('keydown', whenEnterCall(function(event){
  alert('input entered ' + event.target.id);
}));
```

The mdn documentation is a good place to find more about:

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)
- [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)
- [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)
- [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onKeyDownHandler(e)
{
    switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 13:
            if(this.id == "text1"){
            alert("text1 function");
            }else if(this.id == "text2"){
            alert("text2 function");
            }else if(this.id == "text3"){
            alert("text3 function");
            }
          return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.my-input').each(function() {
  $(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
    onKeyDownHandler(this);
  });
});

function onKeyDownHandler(self) {
  //id of the keyup input
  alert($(self).attr('id'));
  //value of the keyup input
  alert($(self).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
text1:
<input type="text" id="text1" class="my-input" />
<br>
<br>text2:
<input type="text" id="text2" class="my-input" />
<br>
<br>text3:
<input type="number" id="text3" class="my-input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('input').keypress(function(e) {
            var key;

            if (e.keyCode) // IE
            {
                key = e.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e.which) //Mozilla
            {
                key = e.which;
            }
            if (key == 13) {
               if(this.id == "text1"){
        alert("text1 function");
        }else if(this.id == "text2"){
        alert("text2 function");
        }else if(this.id == "text3"){
        alert("text3 function");
        }
      return;
            }
        });
```

This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('input').keydown(function (e) {

            if(e.keyCode    == 13)
            {
                if($(this).attr('id')=="text1")
                {
                    alert("text1 function")
                }
                else if($(this).attr('id')=="text2")
                {
                    alert("text2 function")
                }
                else if($(this).attr('id')=="text3")
                {
                    alert("text3 function")
                }
            }
        });

    });
```